# How to maximize a sum of two variables, not just a function

Tags: calculus

I have searched online but can only find methods to maximize functions, not individual variables. I want to maximize the sum $$x+y$$ and I know that $$x+3y = 7.$$

Is their a known method for maximizing the sum of two variables in a function? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know $x,y\geq 0$?

Comment: If there are no further conditions on $x$ and $y$, there is no maximum. For the line $x+y=1000000$ meets the line $x+3y=7$.

Comment: Yes, x,y ≥ 0, Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, $x=7-3y\implies  x+y=7-3y+y=7-2y$

So, the extremes values will be dictated by the nature of $y$

If $y$ can assume any real value $-\infty<y<\infty\implies -\infty<-y<\infty$

What can we say about the range of $7-2y ?$

If $y\ge0,-2y\le0$ and so on

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, x, y ≥ 0

Comment: @Antoine, If $y\ge0,-2y\le 0\iff7-2y\le 7\implies \le 7 $